# Centering issue when using flexbox where the content is larger than the container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to center an element (both horizontally and vertically) with the following conditions:
The element's display is inline-block, since I want its width/height to be calculated depending on its content.

When the container is larger than the element [everything is fine](http://bit.ly/13Ok6eN).

However, the problem starts when the element is larger than the container, and [the element gets the width of the container and not its content](http://bit.ly/12VqEN3).

Thanks in advance,
Oren

Just in case jsFiddle is down, here's the code snippets:

```
<div class="working_area">
    <div class="image_container">
        <img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/bear/bear-05.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.working_area {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;  
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}

.image_container {
  display: inline-block; 
    /*shrink a bit*/
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    /*-webkit-transform-origin: center center;*/
}
```

Comment: Embedded code snippets.

Comment: Is this question specific to image content or any type of oversized content (tables, etc.) and you're just using an image here for simplicity sake?  What do want to happen when the content is larger than `.working_area`?  Should the content shrink or should `.working_area` grow?

Comment: The image center (and image-container's center) should be exactly on top of the working-area center.  The reason is that I do all my zoom in/out with CSS (scale/translate). The image container comprises the image and other layers in it.   The container has "display: inline-block" to automatically have the same size of the image (and his the other layers too), but flex-box "overrides" this and sets its width to 100% instead of the image width.

Comment: Promoting an element to a *flex item* does no such thing.  Flex items shrink to their content (similar to inline-block elements or tables) unless they have a non-zero flex-grow value (btw, you've incorrectly applied the flex property to the *flex container*, it only works on *flex items* -- unless `.working_area` is both a *flex item* and *flex container*).

Comment: The flex property on the container is simply a residue from my code (I tried to remove all non related styles and skipped him accidentally. In my code the working area is both a container and an item, and this does not affect the challenge). Note that image_container has no "flex: 1;".

Comment: Important note: this code worked on previous versions of chrome (I think it broke in version 27), but I didn't find a correlation with their changelog.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding:

```
.image_container img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Makes the `<img>` max out at 100% of the parent, otherwise will only go to it's full width and no wider.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GPhzq/5/)**

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the general challenge to not distort the content (i.e. the max-width scales down the image and later the transform scales up), this solution works for images. This surprised me since observations showed that css-transform is a post-processing which horrific effects on text. I'll vote this elegant answer up so at least you'll get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

set image with percentage to be bigger than the container, and minus margin according to the image size.

Example:

```
.image_container {
    margin:0 -10%;
    width:120%;
}
```

here an example I made on your code

http://jsfiddle.net/GPhzq/3/

Comment: This doesn't seems to be a general solution. Note that after changing the width or height (e.g., to 300 px) the image is no longer centered (and the images are various sizes).  It's easier to view if you add [webkit-transforms](http://jsfiddle.net/GPhzq/4/).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution using Flexbox:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4fuUs/2/)**

(browser specifics included in fiddle)

```
.working_area{
    background: yellow;  
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    text-align:center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.image_container {
  display: inline-block;  
}

img
{
    max-width: 600px; /* limit img to container width */
}
```

### Cross-browser Solution:

Flexbox still isn't supported in all modern browsers (like IE9) so the following solution is probably the preferred way to go:

To horizontally center your image: add `text-align:center;` to the parent container

As for vertical center: being that the working_area has a fixed height, this can easily be achieved. Just add `line-height: 600px`; to the .image_container class and `vertical-align:middle;` to your image class.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4fuUs/)**

So you get:

### Markup

```
<div class="working_area">
    <div class="image_container">
        <img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/bear/bear-05.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.working_area {
  background: yellow;  
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image_container {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 600px;  
}
img
{
    max-width: 600px; /* limit img to container width */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```